# How does Calendar.add work around Daylight Savings time?

Tags: android, calendar, android-alarms, dst

I'm working on an alarm clock app for Android. I'm doing all of my scheduling and timing using the `Calendar` class. I'm curious how `Calendar.add` will respond if the current time is before Daylight Savings Time takes effect but the `add` will push it to be after DST takes effect.

Specifically:

```
// 10 mins from DST taking effect
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
```

If I schedule a `PendingIntent` to broadcast using `c.getTimeInMillis()` will the `PendingIntent` go off in 15 mins (wall clock time from when the moment you set the `AlarmManager`) or will the time change cause it to be in the past or an extra hour in the future?

What can I expect from `Calendar.add` when the amount of time being added spans the time that DST takes effect?

Comment: You would be best off writing a unit test and trying it yourself for that. Just set the date to October 25th and try it. But I think it just adds 15 * 60 * 1000 to the long utc beneath the object

Comment: @bleeding182 That's what I'm hoping it does.

Comment: Writing unit tests is always good. If you're unsure, add a test with what you expect it to do, and if it ever were to be changed, you'd know when building your project suddenly fails ;)

Comment: it seems like it's adjusting to DST / Timezone, too. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#GregorianCalendar.add%28int%2Cint%29